# Excel 2016 don't apply formula if cell is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Hi im using excel 2016 and i need help with some function,let's say i want to use this function to show in N4

`=COUNT(IF(N3=O3,1,0))`

but i want to count as 1 only if the cell is filled , not if it's blank

i tried <>"" and tried all other variations SUMIF or just IF.

Comment: Why are you using COUNT()?  COUNT() returns the count of cells that have numbers in them and your IF only returns numbers so it will always return 1.

Comment: well i can use only IF but that doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Scotts comment does answer your question. The COUNT() function will count every cell as every cell with have a number (0 counts as a number). Try replacing the last zero with a blank string, or even better, use SUMIF() or COUNTIF()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT() returns the count of cells that have numbers in them and your IF only returns numbers so it will always return 1.

Use just the IF

```
=IF(AND(N3<>"",N3=O3),1,0)
```

[image]